# Mime Version an Content-Type showing inside body of my E-mail

Tags: php, email

I am no expert in coding with php and I am having problems with my E-mail. 
The problem is this: I am seeing Mime Version an Content-Type appearing inside my email body.
**So how can I avoid showing this inside my mail body?** THX guys!! 

My mail looks like this: 
MIME-Version: 1.0   **<--want to HIDE THIS!!**

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  **<--and hide THIS!!**

From:Some name

Email: some.mail@yahoo.com

message:
some message

My code:

```
 if (!$errors) { 
            $user = $_POST['email'];

            $mail = 'dejo.dekic@yahoo.com';  //send mail to me
            $subject = 'Kontakt';  
            $tema = 'Info';
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n"; 
            $headers .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n";  
            $headers .= "Message:\n" . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n"; 
            $add_headers = 'From: mail@robertpeic.com' . "\r\n". "Return-path: mail@robertpeic.com" . "\r\n";



            $poruka ='Vaš kontakt je uspjesno zaprimljen! Odgovorit ću vam u najkraćem mogućem roku. Hvala! Molimo ne odgovarajte na ovu poruku. Ova poruka je automatska.';
            mail($mail, $subject, $headers, $add_headers, "-fmail@robertpeic.com");  
            mail($user, $tema, $poruka, $add_headers, "-fmail@robertpeic.com"); 

            echo "<div class='hvala' style='color:white;margin:0px auto;padding-top:20px;width:290px;background-color:white;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;'><p>Hvala Vam na kontaktu!</p></div>";


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
// multiple recipients
$user = $_POST['email'];
$mail = 'dejo.dekic@yahoo.com';  //send mail to me
$subject = 'Kontakt';  
$tema = 'Info';

// message
$message = '
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>From: </td><td>'.$_POST['name'] .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email: </td><td>'.$_POST['email'].'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Message: </td><td>'.$_POST['message'].'</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$_POST['name'].' <mail@robertpeic.com>' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
$poruka ='Vaš kontakt je uspjesno zaprimljen! Odgovorit cu vam u najkracem mogucem roku. Hvala! Molimo ne odgovarajte na ovu poruku. Ova poruka je automatska.';
mail($mail, $subject, $message, $headers, "-fmail@robertpeic.com");
mail($user, $tema, $poruka, $headers, "-fmail@robertpeic.com");
```